# Can't access Array in UseEffect return statement

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, use-effect

I am fetching data in React using axios inside a useEffect hook. When I console log the data from inside the useEffect hook everything is fine, but when I attempt to access it in the return statement, it returns Cannot read property 'Con' of undefined.

Here is my code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/comRes', {headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000/"}})
  .then(function (data) {

    setData(data.data);
console.log(data.data.Con[0])

   })}, []);

  return (

    <div className="grid-container">
    <div className="menu"></div>
  <div className="dashboard">{data.data.Con[0]}</div>
  </div>

  );
```

this is the console.log of of the whole datset:

```
{_id: "5e85c1241c9d440000e730c7", Con: Array(30), Lab: Array(30), LibDem: Array(30), Other: Array(30), …}
_id: "5e85c1241c9d440000e730c7"
Con: (30) [47, 50, 44, 33, 35, 41, 43, 54, 63, 34, 42, 59, 49, 48, 52, 39, 39, 45, 32, 39, 49, 43, 37, 47, 50, 46, 57, 45, 57, 56]
Lab: (30) [31, 28, 34, 47, 42, 33, 35, 23, 19, 44, 34, 21, 28, 29, 34, 36, 39, 31, 11, 29, 33, 45, 52, 41, 30, 38, 28, 29, 25, 22]
LibDem: (30) [9, 9, 10, 9, 11, 11, 8, 8, 9, 10, 9, 9, 14, 9, 4, 8, 8, 10, 6, 5, 10, 8, 5, 7, 11, 7, 9, 14, 11, 14]
Other: (30) [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
Brexit: (30) [3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3]
Green: (30) [4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 8, 4, 5]
SNP: (30) [4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 8, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 3, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Plaid: (30) [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Date: "20/02/2020"
__proto__: Object
```

This is the eror report when I try to access {Data.Con[0]} from the return statement:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210833/discussion-on-question-by-scott-green-cant-access-array-in-useeffect-return-sta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time when your component renders, the data might not be there yet.

My suggestion would be to set the data to `null` by default, so change this line

`const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

to

`const [data, setData] = useState(null);`

Then, **before trying to rendering something, check it is there**

```
<div className="dashboard">{data ? data.Con[0] : null }</div>
```

If you will still have issues, you might want to post the axios's response data structure.

**Update #1**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/comRes', { headers: 
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000/" } 
        }).then(function (data) {
                setData(data.data);
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="grid-container">
            <div className="menu"></div>
            <div className="dashboard">{data ? data.Con[0] : null}</div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: the data is there, because I can render the whole dataset in the <div> by using <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>, but I cannot access any of the items.

Comment: @Dan If you are setting the data by `null` as default, then you don't have to add the `ternary operator` in the div, it will be null if data is not changed.

Comment: @ParthS007, nope, the if is there to avoid calling `.Con` on null

Comment: @ScottGreen, please see my update#1, just copy this code and try it.

Comment: @DanCantir update#1 works!!!!!!   wow! Amazing, thanks Dan - so what was the issue? what was causing the error

Answer (score 0):

It should just be `{data.Con[0]}`

Comment: when I try {data.Con[0]} I get the same result. - cannot access  property 'Con' of undefined. whichever formualation I use, I cannot access the Array from the return statement. It's driving me nuts! I have tried JSON stringifying it as well but it just gives me error messages whichever wy I try to access it.